# How can I provide interactive rotation of an object?

Tags: user-interface, graphics, three.js

In Three.js, there are various Controls, such as TrackballControls, that let the user control the *camera*. This is great, but I want the user to be able to rotate a part of the scene (e.g. a molecule) without rotating the rest of the scene (e.g. a different molecule, or a light source).

Any suggestions on how to do that?

I wonder, if I supplied a different object to the TrackballControls() constructor instead of the camera... would it just rotate that object?? Seems unlikely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate an object you should set its rotation coordinates, so once it's rendered its visual will be updated accordingly. To rotate just one object a time, bind the user input to that particular object rotation parameters.

Check this example, where you can rotate one cube with mouse or touch inputs:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html

And this one, which shows how to select objects using the mouse:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes_tween.html

Comment: So basically, I need to implement it at a lower level (mouseDown / mouseMove events), rather than being able to use a package like trackballControls... or else maybe extend TrackballControls to be able to control another object instead of a camera.

Comment: I had a look at the source code for the various controls here http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src/extras/controls and they are made for general purpose perspective, so I guess there's nothing which stops you from binding them to an object instead of to a camera, have you tried?

Comment: No I haven't... I guess I will give it a try. :-)